# Two projects with crontab on shared server

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have two projects on a shared server with scheduled tasks, so my crontab is like this:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/project1/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * php /path/to/project2/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But only the first command works. Somebody can help?

the commands works directly in terminal

[EDIT]

I solved the problem by specifying the php path because the projects are in different versions of laravel and the version that cron was using did not work in project2.

Comment: If you reverse them does the project2 commands run and project1 do not? You probably want the full path to php in there too.

Comment: Weird .... i remove the first command and it stil does not work.

Comment: Did you try the full path to php? Usually /usr/bin/php

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer. Thanks! :)